# Render antd tree-select drop-down to left side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

Does anyone know how to render an antd tree-select's drop-down to the left side?

I have a tree-select at the right edge of my page/screen. When the drop-down opens, part of it is rendered outside the screen because it renders "to the right"

[image: Example]

Is there a way to make it render to the left side where there is plenty of screen space?

Comment: You can by overwriting `width` property of `.ant-select-tree li span.ant-select-tree-switcher` style. However, why would you still want to do it? Clearly, it is a multiple hierarchy list, so it should look like this. Why not move the entire list more to the left.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a number of other components before this one, in the same row, so there's no space to move it left. The drop-down will render over the other components (temporarily), so for that there's plenty of space on the left.

I did however get around this problem for now by rearranging my components a little. I had another drop-down with a short list of short values, which doesn't need  much space, so I put that at the end of the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean way to do it. However, if you can predict what data will be in the select and dropdown (and don't mind hardcoding some values...), I suggest you to try to fix `width` on `ant-select` and play with `ant-select-dropdown` by fixing its `width` and offset it by providing negative `margin-left` (using `dropdownClassName` [prop of `<TreeSelect />`](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/#Tree-props)). You would have to test it for compatibility in multiple browsers.

[image: example of using negative margin]

Comment: Thanks, even though I've found a way around having to do this, I'm going to accept your answer as it might be helpful to others. Thank you very much for the feedback.